# android - How to change the font of the Switch in xml?

Tags: android

I can change the textview's fonts with using `android:fontFamily="@font/test2"`
 but this is not working on switches, so i created a custom style includes font but still no action. Also I tried with `android:textAppearance="@font/test2"`
 still no action. I can change the font just programmatically. How can I change with using xml attributes?

Comment: Did you try Calligraphy ? It's powerful and also change font for everywhere

Comment: @ArashHatami Thanks for recommendation, I will try it but i wonder why this natural way not working

Comment: In TextView you have only a text ... but here you have two/three drawable and text. I think you should build a custom one and change font for title

Comment: Try using `SwitchCompat` instead, if you aren't using it already.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell I tried with SiwtchCompat still no action.

Answer (score 0):

*android:fontFamily* atribute in xml is not  available for API levels below 16.
For API below 16 use *app* namespace.

Comment: I'm using API 19+